# How do I run a bash script inside Python, but act as if it's running from another directory?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

```
subprocess.call(["/home/blah/trunk/blah/run.sh", "/tmp/ad_xml", "/tmp/video_xml"])
```

I do this.  However, inside my run.sh, I have "relative" paths.
So, I have to "cd" into that directory, and then run the shell script. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not a subprocess expert, but could you do: subprocess.call([""cd /run/path; /home/blah/trunk/blah/run.sh", "/tmp/ad_xml", "/tmp/video_xml"]) ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `cwd` argument to `subprocess.call()`

From the docs here:  http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

> If `cwd` is not None, the child’s
>   current directory will be changed to
>   `cwd` before it is executed. Note that
>   this directory is not considered when
>   searching the executable, so you can’t
>   specify the program’s path relative to
>   `cwd`.

Example:

```
subprocess.call(["/home/blah/trunk/blah/run.sh", "/tmp/ad_xml", "/tmp/video_xml"], cwd='/tmp')
```

Comment: So I should have a subprocess.call above that line?

Comment: This doesn't work. subprocess.call(["cwd /home/blah/trunk/blah/"]) It says OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: You put cwd as an named Python argument.  I added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) with Shell = True and cwd = "Your desired working directory"

**EDIT:** It appears that call has the same arguments so just setting a cwd argument would work:

```
subprocess.call(["/home/blah/trunk/blah/run.sh", "/tmp/ad_xml", "/tmp/video_xml"], cwd="PATH")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can supply your working directory like this:

> subprocess.call(["/home/blah/trunk/blah/run.sh", "/tmp/ad_xml", "/tmp/video_xml"], cwd="/home/blah/trunk/blah")

Answer (score 0):

```
os.chdir(path)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir